# How do I auto refresh a page every time I click the back browser button?

Tags: jsp

I'm using jsp and what I want to do is that after logging out, every time I click the back button, I should always be redirected to my login page (because I have invalidated my session on logout). With every page besides my logout, I check whether there is a session, if there is not, then I am redirected to my login page.

I am able to check the session but every time I click the login button, I'm still able to view my visited pages unless I click the refresh button myself. That's the only time I am redirected to login.

Is there any way I can always be redirected to my login page when I click the back button?

Answer (score 0):

Back button click from browser does not makes a request to the host, hence your not in state to validate session. Instead browser pulls the page from history (cached page).

Either you prevent the cache from the host itself or you can put some client side scripts for preventing the cached view.

For client you could possibly put below script in every jsp/html(view components) which must be seen only for valid session:

**script**

```
<script>
    history.forward();
</script>
```

Comment: Hi. Where actually should I put the script?

Comment: Put on the top of body/content area, it should be before display any content to user..

Comment: Alright thanks! I'll try this out. I won't remove my (if null == session.getAttribute("");"?

Comment: No changes in your existing code, just add my given code snippet.